# How to force NuGet packages Restore in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package-restore

Sometimes i have a bad connection or VPN issues and when I open the project Visual Studio starts to restore the packages and fails.

Is there a way to force NuGet packages Restore in Visual Studio at any time?
Restoring it via command line is not a suitable solution, I'm looking at a solution where i can do it in Visual Studio directly.

Answer (score 0):

In **Visual Studio 2022**, in `Solution Explorer` view, right click on the solution and select `Restore NuGet Packages`

[image]